# Importing maltego module in python

Tags: python, windows, import

I'm trying to import the PyMaltego module and keep getting an import error.

I have already installed the module from the cmd with this command:

```
C:\Documents\maltego>C:\Python32\python setup.py install
```

However, when trying to import the module i get the message:

```
>   File "C:/Users/Loveturd/Documents/Python Stuff/test.py", line 3, in
> <module>
>    import maltego   File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\maltego\__init__.py", line 5, in
> <module>
>     from entity import * ImportError: No module named entity
```

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing on the project Maltego site's that indicate it is python3.2 compatible. This error does not occur if you use python2.7.

You can only use packages with python3.2 if they mention they are python3 compatible.

Comment: No problem. Did you just get into python and started with 3.2 or are you already invested in it and just wanted this module?